# Regex mixed matching of container version tags

Tags: regex

From this list - https://mcr.microsoft.com/v2/dotnet/aspnet/tags/list

I want to match the following

- 6.0-alpine3.13
- 6.0-alpine3.14
- 6.0-alpine3.15
- 6.0-alpine3.16
- 6.0-alpine3.17

But keeping in mind the list could be updated with newer versions .net 6 and alpine which I'd also want to match (not interested in .net beyond 6):

6.<another number with .'s>-alpine<another number with .'s>

E.g.  6.1-alpine4.10

Haven't really been able to get close to matching this accurately so help and explanation appreciated.

and to not match the -amd stuff:
[image]

Comment: Do you mean you need `6\.\d+-alpine\d+\.\d+` ? What about `"6.0.5-alpine3.15"` - should it be matched?

Comment: @markalex I think that's what he means by "another number with .'s" -- the subversion can include `.`

Comment: What problem are you having? `[\d+]+` will match a number including `.`. What more is there to this pattern?

Comment: If you're having trouble, post what you tried and explain where it's failing, and we'll help you fix it.

Comment: @Barmar what engine are you using that `\d` matches `\.`? That and `[\d+]+` seems malformed as opposed to `[\d]+` or even just `\d+`

Comment: @Rogue It was a typo, I meant `[\d.]+`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use websites to help you do regex for you
or even ask for pointers and ideas form ai, regex goes well with them

anyway
`6(\.\d+){1,4}-alpine\d+(\.\d+){0,3}`

6.number and number with up to 3 dots in the middle
the same thing at the end

`{0,3}` is 0 to 3 matches of `(\.\d+)` group, which is a dot and a number after it

#### Update 2. Don't match `-amd` or `-arm`

we add a negative look ahead, which actually was not originally included in regex.
`(?!.*(amd|arm))`
this is the list what not to include `(amd|arm)` if you need amd back just do `(arm)` or add something `(amd|arm|els)`

updated regex:

```
6(\.\d+){1,4}-alpine\d+(\.\d+){0,3}(?!.*(amd|arm))
```

Comment: The `.` after `6` should be `\.` so you could simply use `6(\.\d+){1,4}`

Comment: thx! I missed it.

Comment: So close!  and to not match -amd stuff?  See updated screenshot.  Thanks.

Comment: Not arm not amd? nothing after what is already found?